# How do I add a filter by a tag in grafana?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, telegraf

I feel like I'm trying to do something incredibly simple, but I just can't find any cogent explanation anywhere on the internet after an hour of searching.

I'm using InfluxDB/Grafana and I have a DB with several tables. My tables have a tag key named "host" so that I can tell which server the data is coming from.

I want to create a dropdown on my dashboard so that I can select which host's data is displaying on the panels. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create dashboard variable from the query

```
SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY = "host"
```

and use it in the panel query. It is documented in the Grafana doc: 
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/influxdb/#templating

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that page, and it just wasn't very clear where to put that query or how to use the variable because there are no e2e examples and all the youtube videos I found were using an older version of grafana. In any case, I did eventually get it working after several hours of guess and check